# NPM broken TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined

Tags: macos, npm, azure-devops

NPM has been installed by the Azure DevOps agent install on my mac os Mojave v10.14.6. I can access the npm but any commadn gives tha same error. this is the only command that work
sudo npm --version =6.12.0
sudo npm -p process.platform = darwin

this is the same error message I get for any other command:

> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
>       at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97:27)
>       at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:78:20
>       at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:225:22)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:263:24
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:81:7
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:80:13
>       at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
>       at finalize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:187:14)
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97   var
>   doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true

I have downloaded the latest version node version from nodejs.org and this has not help. 
I believe the problem is that it is missing the .npmrc but i might be wrong.
I ran locate command and here are all the results anything under deb/myagent is azure devops pulled source for building the apps:

Mac-mini:/ sedev$ locate .npmrc

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcsd/node_modules/nsp/node_modules/npmconf/test/fixtures/.npmrc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcsd/node_modules/nsp/node_modules/silent-npm-registry-client/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/npmlog/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/myagent/_work/10/s/app.WebUi/wwwroot/bower_components/vaadin-checkbox/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/myagent/_work/10/s/app.WebUi/wwwroot/bower_components/vaadin-control-state-mixin/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/myagent/_work/10/s/app.WebUi/wwwroot/bower_components/vaadin-element-mixin/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/myagent/_work/10/s/app.WebUi/wwwroot/bower_components/vaadin-grid/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/myagent/_work/10/s/app.WebUi/wwwroot/bower_components/vaadin-grid-5.0.0-alpha6/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/myagent/_work/10/s/app.WebUi/wwwroot/bower_components/vaadin-icons/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/myagent/_work/10/s/app.WebUi/wwwroot/bower_components/vaadin-text-field/.npmrc
/Users/sedev/myagent/_work/10/s/app.WebUi/wwwroot/bower_components/vaadin-themable-mixin/.npmrc
Mac-mini:/ sedev$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was the .npmrc was corrupt or something. I had to remove it and it worked
sudo rm /Users/sedev/.npmrc

Comment: Very appreciate this solution shared here. You can accept this answer thus other SO users could direct know this worked approach:-)

Answer (score 0):

It Is Possible someTime That Node has crashed.
so solution Is That Uninstall NodeJs and Install it Againg

Answer (score 0):

Install for `[ 'browserslist@latest' ] => npm i browserslist@latest`